# 2N3055 Power Supply

Tags: power-supply, transistors, voltage-regulator

Could someone explain how this circuit works and how the output is maintained at 12V?

[schemstic http://www.radanpro.com/Radan2400/Napajanje/7812+2N3055.jpg](http://www.radanpro.com/Radan2400/Napajanje/7812+2N3055.jpg)

There is very little information on how the circuit works online. I know the 12V output from the 7812 is used to bias the power transistor, but how is the voltage at the emitter held at 12V too? Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The diode compensates for the B-E junction.

Comment: Well, it is a voltage regulator... These devices are design to maintain voltage stable what ever the charge you put ( in theory). In real life, after a certain the current draw from the device is so big that it start to diminish the output voltage.

Comment: Another way of saying it : with the diode there, the 7812 output is actually 12.7V.

Comment: The 2n3055 transistor is a current amplifier, the voltage gain is 1, but it allow to  give more current to your load

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, the output is not held at exactly 12 volts. If the 7812 output is at 12 volts, then depending on the current levels at the load the output voltage will be less than 12 volts, and possibly a good deal less.

EDIT - As Russell McMahon pointed out, I was ignoring the diode in the linked circuit. I was also ignoring the fact that 7812s have a nominal output in the range of 11.4 to 12.6 volts. Combining the two suggests that the base voltage will be in the range of 12.1 to 13.3 volts. Apply this as appropriate to the following. In effect, the added diode is intended to compensate for the transistor base-emitter voltage drop. And it does, but not very well. END EDIT

With the base held at 12 volts, the voltage drop of the base-emitter junction will determine the exact output voltage. Since this is a silicon transistor, the usual number is a voltage drop of ~0.7 volts. However, that number really only applies at currents around 1 to 10 mA. For 3 amps you should expect a voltage drop in the range of 1.5 to 1.6 volts. The base current supplied by the 7812 will be multiplied by the gain ($h_fe$ or $\Beta$) of the 3055, so the 7812 does not have to provide an enormous amount of current, although at maximum current the gain will drop, so you might expect a gain of 20 or so, for a base current requirement from the 7812 of 150 mA.

For an open circuit (no load), you can expect about 12 volts from this circuit. At 3 amps, something in the vicinity of 10.5 volts, or maybe a bit lower. This is not a very good circuit (but it is simple and cheap).

The other thing you need to watch out for is power dissipation. At full output and a 24 volt supply, The 2N3055 will be dropping about 13-14 volts, and will be carrying most of the current (at least 95%). So the power dissipated will be about 3 amps times 14 volts, or roughly 40 watts. If you build this, you must provide a fairly beefy heat sink for the transistor. Also note that, due to the low gain at high currents, the 7812 will dissipate significant power. To provide 150 mA of base current at a supply voltage will dissipate .15 amps times 12 volts, or 1.8 watts. This is more than a bare 7812 can handle without going into thermal shutdown, so you will also need a heatsink here as well, although not nearly as big as on the 3055.

Comment: Note the diode n the 7812 gnd lead which pushes 7812 output up to ABOUT 12.5V. They should have an R from 7812 in to diode to get Vdiode up, or even use 2 diodes. Better is to use a transistor across the 7812 so cct gives true ~= 12V out.

Answer (score 2):

In this case the 7812 is used as just the voltage reference for the 2N3055 pass transistor.
If you see the pass transistor as an emitter follower amplifier (where the load is not shown), you see that the output voltage will be just the 7812 voltage minus a Vbe drop. The diode D is a trick to force the reference voltage to be a Vbe drop higher and compensate for the Vbe drop of the 2N3055.

The other parts are only bypass capacitors or capacitors used to enhance the transient response of the circuit.

Answer (score 2):

When an NPN Bipolar transistor is on, there is roughly 0.7V to 1V Vbe (voltage at base relative to emitter). So if you apply 12.7V to the base, you should get about 0.7V less at the emitter - so 12V at the emitter in this case.

As long as there is a load attached, and there is sufficient voltage at the input of the regulator, the transistor will always be driven on, so there will be 0.7V Vbe. If the voltage across the load were to drop the transistor would have to compensate and pull it back up to maintain 0.7V Vbe. If the voltage at the load were to go up the transistor would limit the current as Vbe would drop (turning the transistor off - well slightly more off) which would cause the voltage to drop back down.

By using a 7812, it regulates to 12V at Vout relative to its GND pin. If you add a silicon diode from the GND pin to your circuit ground, there is a voltage drop of 0.7 ish volts across the diode when conducting. This pushes the reference voltage of the 7812 regulator up by 0.7V giving roughly 12.7V at the output.